# Semi-offset Annotated Data

Tags: terminology, nlp, annotated-data

I want to use the [data](http://conll.cemantix.org/2012/data.html) provided by CoNLL 2012 shared task. They mentioned that the data is semi-offset annotated, I couldn't find any interpretation for the term "semi-offset annotation". Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

[Offset annotation](http://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php/Stand-off_markup) is a synonym for stand-off annotation, which is

> the kind of markup that resides in a location different from the location of the data being described by it. It is thus the opposite of inline markup, where data and annotations are intermingled within a single location.

I haven't looked at the data, but apparently part of the annotated material is included in the annotation data (or you have to include it yourself), so it's not fully stand-off markup.

Comment: Is there an example for the offset annotation?